# Resaving blog entries keeps failing

Tags: sections

Recently changed the URL format for a section. Now I have a red circle in the upper right and an error message of "resaving blog entries - failed". Trying again results in same error. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: You might be trying to use a variable in the section path which doesn't exist and is throwing an error. If you haven't already, you may try turning on debug mode in your config file.

Comment: You should also check the craft logs and PHP logs for any obvious errors. You can easily access them from /admin/utils

Comment: Search your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for `[error]` or `[warning]` for any related error messages.

Comment: Check [How do I fix a "stuck" task?](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/stuck-tasks) for task unsticking help.

Comment: @BradBell I get this: Starting step 296 of 301 total steps. in /storage/TasksService.php (235) 2015/04/12 23:06:23 [error] [application] Encountered an error running task 27 (ResaveElements), step 296 of 301: An exception was thrown while trying to save the Entry with the ID “392”: Could not find a unique URI for this element.

Comment: @jimhull what do you see at /admin/entries/SECTION_HANDLE/392?

Comment: @AaronBerkowitz Page not found. The requested URL was not found on this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section that entry #392 belongs to is called `blog` and it's `Entry URL Format` setting is set to `blog/{slug}`.

You also have quite a few entries (100 to be precise), with their slug set to: `snippet` generating a URI for that slug of `blog/snippet`.

That works great for the first one, but when you try to save the 2nd one, Craft sees that `blog/snippet` is already taken and will start appending numbers to the end to try and find a unique URI like so: `blog/snippet-1`, `blog/snippet-2`, etc.

But Craft wants to have a reasonable way to know when to stop trying to find a unique URI, so it will look to the [maxSlugIncrement](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#maxSlugIncrement) config setting and use that, which defaults to 100 - hence the error you're running into.

You either need to 1) use something to generate more unique entry slug formats - like post date/time or 2) increase the maxSlugIncrement config setting to a higher value.