# Resaving Events Entries failed

Tags: sections

This question is identical to [Resaving blog entries keeps failing](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9162/resaving-blog-entries-keeps-failing) except that I'm not finding any [error] or [warning] in my log entries.

I have changed my entry URL format for the section named Events from

```
{mainCategory.last().uri}/{slug}
```

to

```
{mainCategory.last().uri}/_entry
```

as described here: [Is it possible to view 'Expired' entrys on the front end?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8226/is-it-possible-to-view-expired-entrys-on-the-front-end) and when I hit save on the section page, then it immediately gives the failed task: Resaving Events entries. Any thoughts?

UPDATE

OK, I did find this error:
2016/12/18 02:26:41 [error] [application] Encountered an error running task 422 (ResaveElements), step 2 of 197: Encountered the following validation errors when trying to save entry element "Transforming Work" with the ID "19":
 - URI "fort-collins/weekly/buddhist-meditation-classes/_entry" has already been taken.

I'm not sure quite what it means. There's only one entry named Transforming Work.

Comment: I'd recommend going through this: https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks

Comment: I've gone through that pretty thoroughly. No sign of relevant PHP errors or other errors or warnings in the various logs. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Would it be effective to make the change in PHPMyAdmin? I find {mainCategory.last().uri}/{slug} in only one entry in this table: craft_sections_i18n.  But I'm figuring that Craft does some processing when saving, such that making the change manually in that one spot wouldn't actually change anything?

Comment: Correct.  If it immediately fails, it's not likely an environmental limitation.  Reproduce, then check `craft/storage/runtime/logs` for `[error]` and you should see what's tripping it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's only one entry named Transforming Work.

That might be true, but you’re telling Craft to store the entry with an URI

```
fort-collins/weekly/buddhist-meditation-classes/_entry
```

Change your entry URI format back to something that’s going to be unique for each entry, probably you’ll want to replace the hardcoded string `_entry` with the dynamic variable `{slug}` again, or better, do what is actually described in that Stack Exchange answer you linked to and don’t use the default Entry routing at all (disable “Entries in this section have their own URLs”) and rebuild the route with a custom one (see the Craft docs on [Dynamic Routes](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes)).

Comment: Thank you, Carl. I was getting confused by `news/{slug}` → `news/_entry` in that other answer. What I need is very simple, not much more than a template called `archive.html` that contains  `{% set params = { section: 'events', status: 'live,expired', limit: '1000',  order: 'startDate desc' } %}  {% for entry in craft.entries(params) %}<p>{{ entry }}<p>{% endfor %}`.  So thank you very much for getting me back on track.